# PHP - Search File for Contents

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have a PHP script that reads the contents of a file and stores it into a variable. I want to split the text stored by the new line entries and then search the array[0] value for a specific value.

That is my idea. Here is my situation.

I have a directory file with specific entries.

```
Entry1_two_term3_stuff
Entry2_two_term3_stuff
Entry3_two_term3_stuff
```

This will be stored into a variable. How do I search this for Entry2 and then get the whole line to work with?

Comment: What have you tried? You'll usually get the best answers on SO if you are more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, use the file() function to load the file into array, already split by newlines:

```
$lines = file('filename.txt');
```

If not, you can use

```
$lines = explode("\n", $contents);
```

You might want to use \r\n if you're on Windows and file contains CR characters.

To search the array, use foreach:

```
foreach ($lines as $ix => $line)
    if (strpos ($line, 'string') !== false)
        $lines[$ix] = ...new version of line...
```

In the end, write contents back to some file:

```
$fp = fopen('file.txt', 'w+');
foreach ($lines as $line)
    fputs($fp, $line);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Windows uses `\r\n`, not `\n\r`.

Comment: I need to edit this line. When I do so, `$lines` isn't updated. Help?

Answer (score 0):

You could search the directories with `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`, and search the files contents individually with `preg_match_all`